# Spring-Boot Cloug Config Client unable to Autowire

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-cloud-config

I followed a tutorial here: https://www.jianshu.com/p/2ef6a9259112 .

I am unable to autowire the key from my database.

```
 @RefreshScope
 @RestController
 public class MainController {
@Value("${key}")
private String sql;

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@RequestMapping("/showConfig")
@ResponseBody
public String showConfig() {
    String configInfo = "sql key-value pair" + sql;
return configInfo;
}
```

Client bootstrap.properties:

```
spring.application.name=config-client

# This is the default:
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
management.security.enabled=false

spring.cloud.config.label=master
spring.cloud.config.profile=test
server.port=7777
```

Server Properties

```
server.port=8888
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/noob? 
createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=abc123
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.platform= mysql
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=5000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10

spring.profiles.active= jdbc

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.cloud.config.server.default-profile=production
spring.cloud.config.server.default-label=latest

spring.cloud.config.server.jdbc.sql=SELECT `key`, `value` FROM `properties` 
WHERE `application`=? AND `profile`=? AND `label`=?;
spring.cloud.config.server.jdbc.order=0
```

I have these tables made in my noob database:

```
CREATE TABLE `properties` (
  `application` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `profile` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `label` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `key` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

INSERT INTO `properties` (`key`, `value`, `application`, `profile`, 
`label`)
VALUES ('datasource-driver-class- 
name','MyDriverClass','appplication1','production','latest');
```

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.mainController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder '`key`' in value "${`key`}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:380) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at ...
    ... 28 common frames omitted

Comment: Are you sure key @Value("${`key`}") should be surrounded with back-quotes?

Comment: if you followed the tutorial, and with underlying data, the only `@Value`, I 'd expect is: `${datasource-driver-class-name}`, which I'd expect to be `"MyDriverClass"`... :)!?

Comment: you should remove the back-quotes

Comment: @xerx593 I took your advice. I believe it is supposed to work. I want my result to be MyDriverClass but I am getting another error. "Field dataSource in com.example.demo.MainController required a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' that could not be found." This is progress I think.

Comment: ah, good (little progress)! nxt issue: in tutorial he uses "mysql" db , you use "maria"...i know it is "same family", but the driver class (name) is different! (and in another jar/dependency) ...-> pom.xml (find mysql replace with correct driver dependency...google!)

Comment: @xerx593 Thanks, you solved my issues. I had a simple solution but I didn't see it then. I saved some time because of your answers.

Comment: welcome,  @Kev! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the tutorial, and with provided input, you can expect some `@Value` with:

```
@Value("${datasource-driver-class-name}")
private transient String driverClassName;
```

---

> I took your advice. I believe it is supposed to work. I want my result to be MyDriverClass but I am getting another error. "Field dataSource in com.example.demo.MainController required a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' that could not be found."

---

..then, you use "maria", where in tutorial "mysql" db is used, please adjust the according maven dependency:

pom.xml:

```xml
<!-- dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
    <!-- version>1.1.7</version -->
</dependency>
```